# Google doc to base64 string

Tags: google-apps-script, base64, google-docs

[image]

I'm working with apps script. I want to grab a google doc and convert it to a base 64 string to post to an outside app. I've been reading the docs, but am not sure if this can be done.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Document cannot be directly retrieved as the blob with the same mimeType as raw data. I think that this is the specification of Google side. By this, your goal cannot be directly achieved. So as a workaround, how about converting from Google Document to the microsoft DOCX format, and converting it to the base64 data? In this case, it can be achieved using Google Apps Script. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hello @user61629, is the answer provided below of any help to you? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the doc to a blob and then base64 encode the blob's bytes using the built in utilities.

```
function getDocAsBase64String(docId) {
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId)
  const bytes = doc.getBlob().getBytes()
  const base64String = Utilities.base64Encode(bytes)
  const base64WebSafeString = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(bytes)
}
```

Here are the relevant Apps Script doc pages:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getBlob()
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html#getBytes()
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64Encode(Byte)

This page explains the difference between the normal and web-safe base64 strings:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications